# Delphi TCustomTransparentControl dissapears

Tags: delphi

I have created a component using TCustomTransparentControl.
It is working well utill I have more than one instance on the same parent.
When I click on one of the instances the other instances seemingly randomly dissappear. (It is not completely random, but I couldn't figure out the logic)
When I click on the position where the instance is, it is displayed properly.
This is my code.

```
unit TestComponent;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, System.Types, Vcl.Controls,VCL.Graphics,Windows,Messages;

type
  TCustomTransparentControl1 = class(TCustomTransparentControl)
  private
    FPoints:array of TPoint;
    procedure FDoClick(Sender: TObject);
  protected
    procedure Paint; override;
  public
     constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
     destructor Destroy;
     procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams); override;
  published
    { Published declarations }
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('SCADA', [TCustomTransparentControl1]);
end;



{ TCustomTransparentControl1 }

constructor TCustomTransparentControl1.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  ControlStyle := ControlStyle + [csAcceptsControls,csClickEvents];
  interceptmouse:=True;
  Width:=50;
  Height:=50;
  OnClick:=FDoClick;
end;

procedure TCustomTransparentControl1.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited;
  Params.ExStyle := Params.ExStyle or WS_EX_Transparent;
end;

destructor TCustomTransparentControl1.Destroy;
begin
  inherited;
end;

procedure TCustomTransparentControl1.FDoClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Not Focused then
    begin
      SetFocus;
      Invalidate;
    end;
end;

procedure TCustomTransparentControl1.Paint;
begin
  inherited;
  Canvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;
  if Focused then
    begin
      Canvas.Brush.Color := clGreen;
    end
  else
    begin
      Canvas.Brush.Color := clYellow;
    end;
  SetLength(FPoints,4);
  FPoints[0]:=Point(0,0);
  FPoints[1]:=Point(Width,0);
  FPoints[2]:=Point(Width,Height);
  FPoints[3]:=Point(0,Height);
  Canvas.Polygon(FPoints);
end;

end.
```

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: BUG: `destructor Destroy` must be `destructor Destroy; override`

Comment: Also, as a control author, you shouldn't use `OnClick`. Instead, override the `Click` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of errors in your control.

You must override the `destructor`, you must implement handlers for `WM_SETFOCUS` and `WM_KILLFOCUS`, you should not invalidate from mouse click event, you should override `Click()` instead of using `OnClick`, the Paint procedure should use `Width-1` and `Height-1`, no need to override `CreateParams` because it is already done in base class.

Here is my fixed version with all those changes:

```
unit VclTransparentControl;

interface

uses
    Windows,Messages,
    System.SysUtils, System.Classes, System.Types,
    Vcl.Controls,VCL.Graphics;

type
    TCustomTransparentControl1 = class(TCustomTransparentControl)
    private
        FPoints : array of TPoint;
        procedure WMSetFocus(var Message: TWMSetFocus); message WM_SETFOCUS;
        procedure WMKillFocus(var Message: TWMKillFocus); message WM_KILLFOCUS;
    protected
        procedure Paint; override;
        procedure Click; override;
    public
         constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
         destructor Destroy; override;
    published
        property TabStop;
    end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
    RegisterComponents('TestTransparentControl', [TCustomTransparentControl1]);
end;

{ TCustomTransparentControl1 }

constructor TCustomTransparentControl1.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
    inherited Create(AOwner);
    ControlStyle   := ControlStyle + [csAcceptsControls,csClickEvents];
    InterceptMouse := True;
    Width          := 50;
    Height         := 50;
    TabStop        := TRUE;
end;

destructor TCustomTransparentControl1.Destroy;
begin
    inherited;
end;

procedure TCustomTransparentControl1.Click;
begin
    if not Focused then
        SetFocus;
end;

procedure TCustomTransparentControl1.Paint;
begin
    inherited;
    Canvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;
    if Focused then
        Canvas.Brush.Color := clGreen
    else
        Canvas.Brush.Color := clYellow;
    SetLength(FPoints,4);
    FPoints[0] := Point(0,         0);
    FPoints[1] := Point(Width - 1, 0);
    FPoints[2] := Point(Width - 1, Height - 1);
    FPoints[3] := Point(0,         Height - 1);
    Canvas.Polygon(FPoints);
end;

procedure TCustomTransparentControl1.WMKillFocus(var Message: TWMKillFocus);
begin
    inherited;
    Invalidate;
end;

procedure TCustomTransparentControl1.WMSetFocus(var Message: TWMSetFocus);
begin
    inherited;
    Invalidate;
end;

end.
```

Tested with Delphi 10.4.1.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the answer, and it works if I have 2 components on the control, as soon as I have 3 or more, the KillFocus won't happen at least one of them, therefore the invalidate won't happen either.

Comment: I don't know why you select TCustomTransparentControl as ancestor but this is what is causing trouble. At some point, the control invalidate other controls beneath it (the form) and since it is supposed to be transparent, his Paint procedure is not called. If you inherit from TCustomControl if will work (at least it works for me). (Comment out InterceptMouse line).

Comment: Well I wanted a transparent control, TCustomTransparentControl seemed the obvious choice. But I switched to TCustomControl, and will do the transparency another way